# How to get results from different tables with a common column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables following this schema:

1.CardID CardholderID CardNo (...)

2.CardID ClientName (...)

I need to execute a query that can deliver a row with:

```
 CardID | CardholderID | ClientName
```

How do I do this?

I've been looking into subqueries but not really reaching what I need.

Comment: I'd recommend a `JOIN`!

Comment: Consider: `SELECT table1.cardid, table2.firstname FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.cardid = table2.cardid`

Comment: Just corrected the question because I was introducing a wrong column from the result that I wanted.

Comment: @kohhworlwide, I have update my answer as per your revised column list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Join` will help you to achieve joining two tables and fetch records.

```
SELECT t1.CardID, t1.CardholderID, t2.ClientName
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.CardID = t1.CardID
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!
Thank you so much for your help :)